# remove rows in R data frame based on group and another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Have two data frames

```
dat1 <- data.frame(group= c(11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,17,18,18,18),name= c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","A","B","E","F","W","A","B","V"))

dat2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),name =c("A","B","E","F","X","Y"))
```

Second data frame have combinations of two values grouped by ID Column. And based on second data frame (dat2) ,need to remove rows in first data fame (dat1) if that particular **group combination exists in dat2.**

For example: If "A" and "B" **both** exists in dat1 and then it should get removed.

Thus, the desired output is

```
desiredat <- data.frame(group= c(12,12,13,13,15,15),name= c("C","D","G","H","I","J"))
```

Looking for ways in R to achieve the same.

Comment: check your `desiredat` I think there are some values missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by an *anti-join*. However, we need to identify which group ids `group` have to be removed from `dat1`.

```
library(data.table)
# count names per ID
setDT(dat2)[, n.id := .N, by = ID]
# identify groups to remove by joining and ... 
groups_to_remove <- dat2[setDT(dat1), on = "name", nomatch = 0L][
  # ... check which groups have a match with the complete set of names
  , which(n.id == .N), by = .(ID, group)]
# anti join
dat1[!groups_to_remove, on = "group"]
```

> ```
>    group name
> 1:    12    C
> 2:    12    D
> 3:    14    G
> 4:    14    H
> 5:    15    I
> 6:    15    J
> 7:    19    A
> 8:    19    X
> ```

Group 19 is *not* removed because names "A" and "X" belong to different IDs in `dat2`.

---

A more streamlined approach uses `all()` instead of counting the unique names:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)
setDT(dat2)
groups_to_remove <- dat1[dat2, on = "name"][, which(all(ID == ID[1])), by = group]
dat1[!groups_to_remove, on = "group"]
```

> ```
>    group name
> 1:    12    C
> 2:    12    D
> 3:    14    G
> 4:    14    H
> 5:    15    I
> 6:    15    J
> 7:    19    A
> 8:    19    X
> ```

---

The same as above in `dplyr` syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
dat2 %>% 
  left_join(dat1, by = "name") %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(all_have_same_id = all(ID == ID[1L])) %>% 
  filter(all_have_same_id) %>% 
  anti_join(dat1, ., by = "group")
```

> ```
>   group name
> 1    12    C
> 2    12    D
> 3    14    G
> 4    14    H
> 5    15    I
> 6    15    J
> 7    19    A
> 8    19    X
> Warning message:
> Column `name` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
> ```

#### Data

The sample dataset `dat1` provided by the OP consists of groups where either no name is included in `dat2` or all names are in one ID of `dat2` (perhaps plus an additional name) but it lacks a use case where only one name is contained in an ID of `dat2`. Therefore, I have added this use case (as group 19):

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  group= c(11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,17,18,18,18,19,19),
  name= c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","A","B","E","F","W","A","B","V","A","X"))

dat2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),name =c("A","B","E","F","X","Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...?

```
dat1[dat1$name %in% setdiff(dat1$name, dat2$name), ]
3     12    C
4     12    D
7     14    G
8     14    H
9     15    I
10    15    J
15    17    W
18    18    V
```